# Does R support indirect variable expansion or variable substitution?

Tags: r, indirection, variable-substitution

In bash one can use an exclamation mark to use a variable's value as a variable. See [explanation here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41292/13399). This is known as variable indirect expansion. This can be used to used to name a new variable using another variable in your code. I was wondering if this could be done in R lang.

For example, lets say I want to create a data frame of employees located at each of a companies' buildings.

```
head(talent_by_building)

   employee building
1    345618 Pi
2    195871 E
3    247274 Pi
4    929771 Pi
5    873096 E
6    665857 E
7    791656 E
8    133673 E
9    574058 C
10   208041 C
11   402100 C
12   167792 C
13   156971 C
```

And let "*♠building*" be the variable I want to indirectly expand. So I want to use the building name as a new variable of that building's name. I am using a ♠ character here because using ! (as it is used infront of a variable in bash) was causing some confusion.

```
completed_list <- c("") #Clear out vector
for(building in talent_by_building$building){

  if(!(building %in% completed_list)){
    ♠building<-talent_by_building[talent_by_building$building %in% building,]
  }
  append(completed_list,building)
}
```

If this was possible in R, the expected output would be the creation of three new data frames named for each of the buildings the for loop found. Pi,E,and C:

```
head(pi)

   employee building
1    345618 Pi
2    247274 Pi
3    929771 Pi


head(E)

   employee building
1    195871 E
2    873096 E
3    665857 E
4    791656 E
5    133673 E

head(C)

   employee building
1   574058 C
2   208041 C
3   402100 C
4   167792 C
5   156971 C
```

Is there a way to use the building name as the name of the new value? So in place of *♠building* the value of the variable would be substituted as the variable name. I can do this in bash and was wondering if this was possible in R.

Comment: It'd be easier if you make the input reproducible, ie. use `dput` or something similar so that we can easily copy-n-paste into R and have your example ready

Comment: I don't understand the desired output here. Please define all variables to make your problem [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). I think you just want `x[[building]]<-` maybe? But i don't know what `x` is supposed to be here. Rather than asking to translate syntax, focus on describing the problem you want to solve in R.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have replaced x[building] with ♠building. This is to symbolize the R functionality I am looking for. I am not looking for corrections to my grammar. I also cannot provide all my code as it is company code and having working code is irrelevant to the question. I am not looking for correct code. I am looking for an R equivalent of a feature I use in bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** no, there is no short-hand syntax for variable substitution.  *Slightly longer answer*: it's pretty easy to get your desired output. If you're going to be working with R for more than a very short time, it's probably worth learning some R idioms, though.

Construct example data:

```
talent_by_building <-  read.table(header=TRUE,text=
"employee building
345618 Pi
195871 E
247274 Pi
929771 Pi
873096 E
665857 E
791656 E
133673 E
574058 C
208041 C
402100 C
167792 C
156971 C")
```

First split the data by `building`:

```
ss <- split(talent_by_building,talent_by_building$building)
```

The idiomatic R way to deal with these data would be to leave them *inside* the list rather than creating new variables to clutter up the global workspace.  But if you want to:

```
for (i in names(ss)) {
    assign(i,ss[[i]])
}
ls()
```

A more direct translation of your code:

```
BUILDING <- "Pi"
assign(BUILDING,subset(talent_by_building,building==BUILDING))
```

If you want to do something other than assignment you can use `eval()`, `substitute()`, and/or `parse`, but it's usually more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: So I guess you are saying that lang R does not have this functionality built into its grammar?

Comment: `list2env(ss, .GlobalEnv)` is more convenient than the `assign` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The functions 1) `expression`, `quote` and `bquote` and 2) `eval` might be what you are looking for (some kind of indirection if I correctly understood).